# How can I generate a JSON file from a flat buffer schema

Tags: flatbuffers

For example if I have the following flat buffer schema:

```
table table_1 {
    field1:uint32_t;
    field2:uint32_t;
}

table table_2 {
    field3:string;
    field4:table_1;
}

root_type table_2;
```

Is there a way to automatically generate the Json file:

```
{
    "field3": "",
    "field4": {
        "field1":"",
        "field2":""
    }
}
```

So it will be easier to fill the Json file and generate a bin file.

I just need to implement a reader and not a builder.

Thanks

Comment: There's no option to generate an "empty" JSON from a schema, no. It also is not easy to provide that functionality, since many things are designed to optional, and having them output in a JSON would just make it very verbose and not that helpful. Same with how many elements you want in a vector, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way, but you could use the [reflection API](https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/blob/master/include/flatbuffers/reflection.h) to do it yourself. Generate the binary schema using `flatc`, read in that binary schema into your own application and iterate over the tables and fields and export it as JSON.

I recently wrote a Lua generator that follows this scheme, and you could something [very similar](https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/blob/1a4c405662a4a7a448ea5a21a6ae6ea43d4f096c/src/bfbs_gen_lua.cpp#L56-L63).